# Split строки используя шаблон условного оператора

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, транслятор

Пишу транслятор, преобразующий языковую конструкцию if else на C# в ПОЛИЗ, для этого необходимо рассплитить входную строку по шаблону "if(<условие>){<оператор 1>} else {<оператор 2>} <оператор 3>". С регулярными выражениями не работал никогда, какого-то генератора по шаблону не нашел, а костыли а-ля input.Substring(input.IndexOf('('),...) делать не хочется.

Comment: Достать нужно конкретно условие и операторы.

Comment: Лучше дайте пример входных данных и то, что хочется получить на выходе. +, возможно, полезным метод будет https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SanŚ́́́́Ý́́́́Ś́́́́ Ну например (будем считать, что переменные уже где-то инициализированы), входные данные:  "if (n>5) {n = n-1;} else {n = n%2;} k = n;" , выходные - получить подстроки "n>5", "n = n-1;", "n = n%2;", "k = n".

Comment: А тому методу как раз таки нужна строка в виде регулярного выражения, а я не знаю как шаблон задать.

Comment: Исходная строка со всеми разделителями и форматированием берется из кода или выражение преобразовано в одну "длинную" строку без переносов? Всегда соблюдаются указанные условия (пара {} после if и else, только один оператор в теле) ?

Comment: @Aleksandr Zharinov это уже вопросы валидации конечно, и чем больше вариантов охватывается, тем лучше, но допустим что все условия соблюдаются, а в теле может быть несколько операторов. Исходное выражение - "длинная" строка, введенная пользователем. Это имеет принципиальное значение (откуда исходное выражение)? Или вы намекаете на рефлексию и извлечение бубнами метаданных?

Comment: К тому же, если шаблон в виде регулярного выражения будет доставать всё, находящееся в теле, то имеет ли значение, сколько и чего в теле лежит?

Comment: Полагаю, эти правила важны для составления шаблона регулярного выражения. Насчет количества операторов в теле соглашусь - это действительно неважно.
Попробуйте для начала вот такую конструкцию:
    string input = <YourInputString>;
    string pattern = @"if\(|\)|{|}|else";
    var result = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Where(el => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(el));

Comment: В комментариях не все символы отображаются. Не забудьте экранировать все нужные символы.

Comment: **if\s+\((.+?)\)\s+\{(.+?)\}\s+else\s+\{(.+?)\}\s+(.+);**
группы 1-4 соответствуют блокам, можете на regex101 ввести и протестировать онлайн визуально.

Comment: @WeNeedToGoDeeper Спасибо большое, работает, правда в полученной сплитом коллекции почему-то первый блок дублируется, ну и в начале и конце пустые строки, поправил это так : var elements = Regex.Split(input, pattern).Where(s=>s!="").Distinct().ToList();

Comment: @Сергей сайт съел экранирование скобок, поставьте слеш вместо подчеркивания: **if\s+_((.+?)_)\s+\{(.+?)\}\s+else\s+\{(.+?)\}\s+(.+);**  С пустыми строками не знаю причину, но вы ведь уже справились)

Comment: @WeNeedToGoDeeper, пожалуйста, оформите ваши комментарии в виде ответа.